# How to time travel(rollback) in a state tree using Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How can I achieve a time travel feature using Vuex ? I want to go back for a previous state, to undo something.

Is that possible out of the box ?

Any idea on how to achieve that ?

was hoping for something like `store.rollback(1)`

Answer (score 7):

The best approach is *not* to keep the record of the state snapshots, but rather, keep the record of committed mutations.

To UNDO one step:

- reset the state to initial
- reapply all mutations but last

This approach is easier on the memory (esp if you have a large store), and is more in line with how the store should be treated.

A very good breakdown here:

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/13/vue-js-vuex-undo-redo/

A working solution here:

https://github.com/anthonygore/vuex-undo-redo

Answer (score 5):

Just implement it by your own, add a prevState to your store, you can only select the parts that you want to make it undo-able.

Here is the simplest example, which only support 1 history record:

**store**

```
const state = {
  count: 0,
  prevCount: null
}
```

**mutations:**

```
const INCREMENT = state => {
  state.prevCount = state.count
  state.count += 1
}

const UNDO = state => {
  if (state.prevCount !== null) {
    state.count = state.prevCount
    state.prevCount = null
  }
}
```

If you need to have more history, just put them in an array

```
const state = {
  count: 0,
  countHistory: []
}
```

and then you can use `state.countHistory.pop()` and `state.countHistory.push(xx)` to undo/save records

Another solution is [plugin](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/plugins.html) (middleware), in case you want to save all the history automatically.

Comment: I believe that should do it. Was hoping for something  more built-in. I guess I could use a middleware that store the previous payload to be more generic. Thanks for the help